# KDB+/Q: how to find all entries in a dictionary matching a certain value?

Tags: kdb

The find function `?` returns the first matching entry in a dictionary for the given value:

```
q)d:1 2 3 4!100 200 100 400
q)d
1| 100
2| 200
3| 100
4| 400
q)d?100
1
q)
```

How would I find all the entries in the dictionary matching that value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q)d:1 2 3 4!100 200 100 400
q)where d=100
1 3
```

Comment: Nice! Very elegant. However, this will simply return the indices, you still need a step to get the keys themselves

Comment: This is not true. The indices would be `0 2`, not `1 3`. You can further see that this idiom works by applying it to the following dictionary: `d:"abcd"!100 200 100 400`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I made a mistake when testing earlier

Answer (score 2):

A naive implementation would be something like this:

```
f: {(key x) where (y=) value x}
f[d;100] /returns 1 3
```

Basically, find which indices have the value you are looking for and get the matching keys